# How "docker run" works for different executable other than bash?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Docker command run:

*docker run -it image_name [commands]*

Executes **commands** inside bash process of the Docker container.

I recently came across an example where **commands** was being executed in a different interpreter, like **python** for example. That is, if I were to run the following command:

*docker run -it image_name --version*

I would see the version of python. How is this actually implemented in the Dockerfile to shift the default executable environment to some other program?

Comment: https://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2016/08/21/container-entrypoint/

Comment: Have a alook at the ENTRYPOINT command

Comment: "other than bash" you are concluding the SO has bash. For instance, I use alpine linux, which does not have bash, but sh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's understand this by considering the following examples:

```
# cat Dockerfile 
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python
```

This **Dockerfile just installs the python packages** and build the docker image through which you can run the commands something like these:

```
# docker run -it example:3.0 /bin/bash
root@ee65d228ce3b:/# 
root@ee65d228ce3b:/# which python
/usr/bin/python
root@ee65d228ce3b:/# python --version
Python 2.7.6
root@ee65d228ce3b:/#
```

Let's another Dockerfile which is slightly different from the above:

```
# cat Dockerfile 
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python 
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/python"]
```

The **additional thing in this Dockerfile is that it has ENTRYPOINT** which says that when you run the docker image that is build from this Dockerfile, it executes the command that is part of it. So it can run as:

```
# docker run -it example:2.0 --version
Python 2.7.6
```

This way you can customize the Dockerfiles and can run the script or executables.